# how to style a string within a html template

Tags: html, pug

I get an array with strings in my html template (pug/jade). Then I do this

```
each row, i in log
    p= row
```

The string/row Looks something like this:

```
[12-12-2019 15:00:00][INFO] Message Test...
```

Now I want to Color the info text. How can I do this?
I tried this:

```
each row, i in log
    p= row.replace("[INFO]", "[<span style='color: blue'>INFO</span>]")
```

but then I only get the element as plain text on the site.

---

Edit:
Thats what is displayed on the page with this Methode:

```
[12-12-2019 15:00:00][<span style='color: blue'>INFO</span>] Message Test...
[12-12-2019 15:00:00][<span style='color: blue'>INFO</span>] Message Test...
[12-12-2019 15:00:00][<span style='color: blue'>INFO</span>] Message Test...
```

Comment: there's a whitespace in `[INFO ]` in `p= row.replace("[INFO ]", "[<span style='color: blue'>INFO</span>]")` that's probably causing the replace to not work, as in `[12-12-2019 15:00:00][INFO] Message Test...` line `[INFO]` does not have any whitespace.

Comment: Oh sorry, thats just a typo. I will Change my Question ^^

Answer (score 1):

In pug there's a feature called "tag interpolation". `#[strong Something important]` becomes `<strong>Something important</strong>`

For your example, replace `<span>` with `#[span ...]`:

```
each row, i in log
    p= row.replace('[INFO]', '[#[span(style="color: blue") INFO]]')
```

Comment: That dosn't seem to work. Now I get `[#[span(style='color: blue') INFO]]` on my page. Even when I do this it doesnt work: `p= '[ #[span(style="color: blue") INFO]]'`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work :)
I needed to write it like that:

```
each row, i in log
    div. 
        !{row.replace("[INFO]", '[<span style="color: blue">INFO</span>]')}
```